# Como obter dados do pedido do usuário no banco Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, kotlin

Tenho um app Android em Kotlin que faz pedido delivery de pizza onde a empresa recebe os dados do pedido do usuário e quero que o usuário também receba os dados do pedido que ele fez, há algum tempo tento e não acho a solução. Segue método deve recuperar dados do pedido na classe de ver pedidos:

```
   private fun recuperarDados() {

        dialog = SpotsDialog.Builder()
            .setContext(this)
            .setMessage("Aguarde")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .build()
        dialog!!.show()



        val pedidoRef = idEmpresa?.let {
            idUsuarioLogado?.let { it1 ->
                firebaseRef
                    ?.child("pedidos_usuario")
                    ?.child("itens")

            }
        }

        val pedidoPesquisa = pedidoRef?.child("status")?.equalTo("confirmado")

        pedidoPesquisa?.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {

                pedidos.clear()
                if (dataSnapshot.value != null) {
                    for (ds in dataSnapshot.children) {
                        val pedido = ds.getValue(ItemPedido::class.java)
                        itemPedidos.add(pedido!!)

                    }
                    adapterPedido!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
                    dialog!!.dismiss()

                }




            }

            override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {

            }
        })


    }
```

Comment: Bom dia! Então são dois apps diferentes? Um para o user e outro para a empresa?

Comment: isso mesmo, são dois

Answer (score 2):

Eu faria a estrutura da base desta maneira

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Para filtrar pelo lado da empresa os pedidos

```
val pedidoPesquisa = mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child("pedidos")
            .orderByChild("idempresa")
            .equalTo(1);//seu id da empresa
```

> Para filtrar pelo lado do usuario os pedidos

```
   val pedidoPesquisa =  mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child("pedidos")
            .orderByChild("idusuario")
            .equalTo(1);//seu id de usuario
```

> Para executar a busca

```
   pedidoPesquisa?.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {

            if (dataSnapshot.value != null) {
                for (ds in dataSnapshot.children) {
                    val pedido = ds.getValue(ItemPedido::class.java)
                    itemPedidos.add(pedido!!)

                }
                adapterPedido!!.notifyDataSetChanged()

            }

        }

        override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {

        }
    })
```

Comment: Como o recycleview pode receber esses dados?

Comment: Tentei no recycleview mas me retorna null

Comment: uma pergunta, vc quer listar todos os pedidos com status "confirmado"? ou vc quer pegar os itens de um pedido?

Comment: Com status "confirmado"

Comment: depois de confirmado o pedido vai para um status de finalizado?

Comment: Eu fiz confusão na explicação, como faço pra refazer minha explicação?

Comment: Firebase é mais trabalho de como montar a estrutura e o que vc vai consultar, eu acho que vc quer listar os pedidos confirmados para a empresa e os mesmos que vc fez como usuario, eu faria separado os que estão em andamento e vc esta aguardando e os outros que finalizaram mesmo que tenha que copiar os dados de uma lista para outra quando finalizar, não sei se vc ta me entendendo mas posso tentar montar uma estrutura pra vc e vc ve se serve para seu projeto

Comment: Eu agradeceria, eu só preciso trazer os pedidos feitos pelo cliente pra ele ver o que pediu

Comment: Até então, só não consigo recuperar o nó  itens que está no nó pedidos, no demais consigo retornar outros nós como a lista de empresas, por exemplo

Comment: Faz sentido isto pelo seu codigo isto acontecer, dentro do seu nó itens tem o id do cliente? se não tiver inclui, e para cada pedido seu faça um id semelhante ao que eu te respondi la, por que ai vc consegue filtrar usandochild("pedidos_usuario")
            .orderByChild("idcliente")
            .equalTo(1);

Comment: Conseguiu entender a explicação o Firebase as vezes é confuso mesmo de buscar coisas é diferente por exemplo de um banco SQL eu tenho dificuldade de conseguir contruir coisas lá tambem

Comment: Eu consegui resolver de outra forma, com a ajuda de um amigo